# spring mvc validation messages

Tags: spring, validation, spring-mvc

I have a problem figuring out how to pass validation properties from spring to the externalized messages. I am using spring 4, and already included "validation-api-1.1.0.Final" and "hibernate-validator-5.2.1.Final".

my Model:

```
@Size(min=20, max=64)
private String email;
```

I am still getting the message of "**email shouldn't be empty TCH {2} {1} {0}**" when I return to the form.

My validationMessages.properties has the following line in it:

- Size.virement.email=email shouldn't be empty TCH {2} {1} {0}

I also tried using *{min}* and *{max}*, as well as *%1* and *%0*. None of these work.

My xml config for spring has the following configuration:

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basenames">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:content/ValidationMessages</value>
                <value>classpath:content/Language</value>
                ...
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    </bean>
```

I also did include the *spring-context-4.1.5.RELEASE* library.

Any idea ??
Note that I am using thymeleaf to render the view.

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically have an error message template, which you would like to populate with the values of the given constraint.

I think you can achieve this with an custom ConstraintValidor.

See the Hibernate reference here, especially the section 3.1.2.1:
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.1/reference/en-US/html/validator-customconstraints.html

I hope it gives some idea!

Comment: Hi and thank you for your quick response. I used what you are referring to here, but only to create a custom validation, like checking if 2 email field match.  In all the examples I saw about validating basic annotation, like min and max, they all go without using custom validators.

Comment: I see, I think the problem that you don't use the default validation message keys, like "javax.validation.constraints.Size=The text must be between {min} and {max} chars long". Where do you set the message key "Size.virement.email" exactly?

Here is more info, in the reference: http://beanvalidation.org/1.0/spec/

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, but I remember I read that in many articles: you write your validation message as <constraint>.<bean>.<field> in your externalized messages properties file.  Besides, if the message is wrong, it should not display.  my problem is that it is displayed, however the values are not replaced.

Comment: I think you should use the _common_ message keys. If you want to use own message keys, like "<constraint>.<bean>.<field>" you have to specify them in the annotation and use a custom constraintvalidation as i mentioned in my original answer.

Comment: for now, I did what you suggested.  I have overridden the default messages, like this: *javax.validation.constraints.Size.message=La taille doit etre entre {min} et {max} xxxxxx*. And if the user wishes to have a custom message, it would still be localized, but without placeholders for min and max.

Comment: for now, I did what you suggested.  I have overridden the default messages, like this: *javax.validation.constraints.Size.message=La taille doit etre entre {min} et {max} xxxxxx*. And if the user wishes to change my message, he has to write his message without placeholders for min and max.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven validator="validator"/> 

<bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean">
    <property name="validationMessageSource" ref="messageSource"/>
</bean>
```

Example:

```
Size.user.name=Invalid username
```

And please note that `user` in  is value of `ModelAttribute` in your `Controller` (`@ModelAttribute("user")`.